# Create new dataframe with one row for each pair of rows with consecutive sequence in existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, point

I have an existing dataframe where each row represents a geographical point. Each point is defined by a unique ID, a user-defined sequence number and its pair of geographical coordinates, as follows:

```
id  Sequence Latitude Longitude Trajectory
544        0 41.37990   2.17220          1
545        1 41.37874   2.17104          1
546        0 41.37867   2.17092          2
547        1 41.37863   2.17084          2
548        2 41.37857   2.17073          2
549        3 41.37853   2.17065          2
```

Note that these points from a series of trajectories where each trajectory is formed by consecutive points following the sequence variable. I also have an existing variable 'Trajectory' grouping these consecutive points. So, in this example, there is a trajectory of two points followed by a trajectory of 4 points.

I need to create a new dataframe (let's call it "lines") where I need one row for each line joining two consecutive points in the same trajectory. Each row needs to contain the two point indices and its two pairs of coordinates and, ideally, the trajectory number. So the result for the previous example would be:

```
Line  id1 Latitude1 Longitude1 id2 Latitude2 Longitude2 Trajectory
0     544  41.37990    2.17220 545  41.37874    2.17104          1
1     546  41.37867    2.17092 547  41.37863    2.17084          2
2     547  41.37863    2.17084 548  41.37857    2.17073          2
3     548  41.37857    2.17073 549  41.37853    2.17065          2
```

I have been trying to use libraries such as tidyverse, dplyr and similar ones to avoid using for loops, as I know they are not efficient and the existing dataframe has millions of points, but nothing has worked and I cannot find any similar problem.

Any help on how to tackle the problem will be welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the original data is sorted by trajectory and sequence as your example, I can shift one row in longitude, latitude and trajectory columns to make longitude 1/2, latitude 1/2 and trajectory 1/2, and then extract rows with the same trajectory.

Suppose the original dataframe is "points":

```
n = nrow(points)
temp <- data.frame(
  id1 = points$id[1:(n-1)],
  Latitude1 = points$Latitude[1:(n-1)],
  Longitude1 = points$Longitude[1:(n-1)],
  id2 = points$id[2:n],
  Latitude2 = points$Latitude[2:n],
  Longitude2 = points$Longitude[2:n],
  Trajectory1 = points$Trajectory[1:(n-1)],
  Trajectory2 = points$Trajectory[2:n]
)
temp=temp[Trajectory1==Trajectory2,]
n = nrow(temp)
ret <- data.frame(
  Line = c(0:(n-1)),
  id1 = temp$id1,
  Latitude1 = temp$Latitude1,
  Longitude1 = temp$Longitude1,
  id2 = temp$id2,
  Latitude2 = temp$Latitude2,
  Longitude2 = temp$Longitude2,
  Trajectory = temp$Trajectory1
)
```

ret is output.

Comment: Nice observation! Hadn't thought about shifting one row, great idea. It works like a charm, much faster than [@det approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67017713/12437060) (still thanks, though!). I also appreciate that it uses base R and that it is so clear and easy to understand. Thank you very much!